# Split an Array of arrays into 2 separate arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a hash with some key value pairs as below:

```
@level2 = @l2.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,element|
hash[element] +=1
hash }
```

I perform some sorting on the hash based on the keys.

```
@level2 = @level2.sort_by { |x, _| x }.reverse
```

Now I assume that the sort_by gives me an Array of Arrays. I want to split this into 2 arrays such that my first array should contain all keys and second array should contain all values.

The hash#keys and hash#values are not accessible after sorting the hash. So that does not work in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of how you make the hash it will will have a `Hash#keys` method and a `Hash#values`. They both return arrays that are just what you seem to want.

```
keys_array   = @level2.keys
values_array = @level2.values
```

Comment: I have one more problem here. I am sorting the hash based on my values. These 'keys' and 'values' methods do not work after I sort the hash. So how do I split the hash after sorting it ? I have edited the question, please check it

Comment: `#sort_by` returns an array of arrays. Arrays do not have keys. How to sort that data structure is another question entirely.

Comment: I changed the question and edited it. Can you please help me resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array of arrays and add each element to a new array. This would keep the order of the elements.

```
keys_array = []
values_array = []
@level2.each do |key, value|
  keys_array << key
  values_array << value
end
```